# java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "[14.8678]"

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have `Array[Row]` but indeed it always contains only a single `Row` with a Double value. I want to extract this Double value into a parameter `param1`:

```
val q1 = spark.sql("SELECT PERCENTILE(price,0.25) FROM table").collect()

val param1 = q1.mkString(",").toDouble
```

But I get this error:

```
17/11/20 14:05:52 ERROR ApplicationMaster: User class threw exception: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "[14.8678]"
```

How can I obtain a number from `Array[Row]`. Currently, I use `collect()`, but maybe it's easier to grab a number directly from DataFrame?

Comment: `spark.sql("SELECT PERCENTILE(price,0.25) FROM table").map(_.getDouble(0) ).collect`

Comment: @philantrovert: This gives me `Array[Double]`

Comment: If you only have one value in there then change it to `collect.apply(0)`

Comment: @philantrovert: Thank you! Could you please post your answer so that I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you collect a dataframe, it gives you an `Array[Row]` and those square brackets are part of the `Row` object.

```
sqlContext.range(2).collect.foreach(println)
[0]
[1]
```

`Row` objects have predefined functions like `getDouble` , `getString`, `getDate` to fetch the values from them.

You also have following alternatives semantically :

```
sqlContext.range(2).withColumn("doub", $"id".cast("double") ).map(_.getDouble(1) ).collect
res3: Array[Double] = Array(0.0, 1.0)

sqlContext.range(2).withColumn("doub", $"id".cast("double") ).map(_.getAs[Double](1) ).collect
res4: Array[Double] = Array(0.0, 1.0)

sqlContext.range(2).withColumn("doub", $"id".cast("double") ).map(_.getAs[Double]("doub") ).collect
res5: Array[Double] = Array(0.0, 1.0)

sqlContext.range(2).withColumn("doub", $"id".cast("double") ).select("doub").as[Double].collect
res9: Array[Double] = Array(0.0, 1.0)
```

Comment: I selected: `val q1= spark.sql("SELECT PERCENTILE(price, 0.25) FROM campaign_products").map(_.getDouble(0)).collect.apply(0)`. But what happens if `price` is empty or `null`?

Comment: Don't use `getDouble` then. All other methods should give you `0.0` wherever `price` is `NULL`.

Comment: Do you mean that I should use `getString` instead of `getDouble`?

Comment: No, use `getAs[Double]`. It will do the casting for you .

Comment: `spark.sql("SELECT PERCENTILE(price, 0.25) FROM campaign_products").map(_.getAs[Double]).collect.apply(0)`. Cannot compile it now.

Comment: You haven't provided the column index or name after `getAs[Double]`. Make it `getAs[Double](0)` or `getAs[Double](col_name)`